# Angular 1.x ES6 Webpack include 3rd party libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am developing an app using starter project : https://github.com/shprink/angular1.4-ES6-material-webpack-boilerplate.

I am stuck when I need to use 3rd party library.
I want to use js-yaml https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml

I try to add it in my angular service:

```
import jsyaml from  '../../node_modules/js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js';
```

But I get error:

```
bundle-0d6476.js:75756 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../node_modules/js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js"
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [the docs on resolving modules](https://webpack.github.io/docs/resolving.html). To import modules from `node_modules`, specify the path omitting everything up to and including `node_modules`. Thus, `import jsyaml from  'js-yaml/bin/js-yaml.js'` should work.